# How to make the webgrid first row data is selected(highlighted) when a razor view is loaded?

Tags: javascript, webgrid, w3.css

I am using webgrid in the razor view of my mvc web app,  a razor view contains a webgrid,  I want to make the first row data to be selected by default when the page is loaded every time.

A .css called "selectRow" has been created as this:

```
.selectRow {
 background: black;
 color : white;}
```

I have tried this, but it doesn't work, any idea how to make it working? much appreciated! the "WebgridId" is the htmlAttributes of current webgrid

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#WebgridId tr').find("first").addClass('selectRow');
})
```

Comment: Can anybody help?

Comment: It seems this is difficulty question? I haven't received any response so far...